# How to achieve Java-8 Lambda functionality in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am new to Groovy framework and want to have a script in which we need to get the latest date out of many. I tried to use Java-8 Lambda to achieve it but getting compile time error stated

```
l.stream().max(Date::compareTo).get();
```

My feature code is mentioned below if some one can rectify it:

```
String date1 = parseDate("2020-09-12");
String date2 = parseDate("");
String date3 = parseDate("2019-01-12");

List<Date> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(date1);
l.add(date2);
l.add(date3);

Date maxDate = l.stream().max(Date::compareTo).get();

print(maxDate);

private LocalDate parseDate(String date) throws Exception {
    try {
        return LocalDate.parse(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Date.compareTo` is not correct in either Java or Groovy. But your description said you used `Date::compareTo`? Just note that only Groovy 3+ supports Java's style of lambda expressions and method references.

Comment: And just so you know, in Groovy you can just use `Date maxDate = l.max()`. If `l` is empty, you'll get back null (which you seem to assume won't happen, given your unconditional call to `get()`)

Comment: yes @ernest_k correct about Date::compareTo. I rectified in question and We are using Groovy 2.4. So, can you help how we can achieve it?

Comment: why would anyone want to achieve java8 functionality in Groovy?

Comment: You are attempting to put `String` instances in a `List<Date>`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Groovy older than 3, you can pass a closure:

```
Date maxDate = l.stream().max({a,b -> a.compareTo(b)}).get();
```

But it's even simpler, as Groovy lets you just use

```
Date maxDate = l.max()
```

This is even safer than the unconditional call to `get()`, which can cause your program to crash.